# Graphs in Kibana Visualize

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to create a visualization in Kibana which will give me the average number of logs per hour per day. Can someone guide me to create a visualization as shown below. I had tried to reach out to the elastic discussion website with a similarquery and the team did share a solution but I could not implement it at my end. The link to my question is given below https://discuss.elastic.co/t/average-number-of-info-logs-in-a-particular-time-period/142698/2 [image]

Comment: Hi @sachinb, I'm confused by the word average. Do the start-end dates of you example are the beginning and end of the week, or are they broader dates and you want to create weekly averages for every tuple?

Comment: Hi @baleato , by start date and end date , I mean any range from one date to another date. For example I might want a report from 6-Aug-2018 to 19-Aug-2018. Now this is spread over two weeks and I want the average logs which I will receive hourly for Monday (6-Aug, 13-Aug), Tuesday (7-Aug, 14-Aug) etc. Let me know if I am clear in my explanation. Thanks